# 1Mhz+ AC resistance measurements

Tags: ac, resistance

Is a four point probe applicable for resistance/impedance measurements at high frequencies?

Is there a more common technique for AC resistance/impedance measurements?

Background:
I'm coating fibers and trying to characterize the coating and make sure it's close to the base material and the coating process didn't mess anything up.  I've setup my four point probe for DC measurements and that works fine but now I'm interested in AC measurements as well.  Instruments to measure voltage and current at high frequencies are more expensive so I was wondering if there was another way.

Edit for comments:
@George Herold - I'm interested in conductance and it's the [Kelvin four point probe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-terminal_sensing)

@Oleg Mazurov - I'm interested in the skin effect.  We're trying to demonstrate our coated fibers do better than a solid wire, at least on a by mass basis.

Comment: You are trying to measure AC conductivity?  (or capacitance?)  There will be some cable capacitance, but how important that is will depend on the impedance you are looking at. (Which you didn't mention.)  You might start at lower frequencies (1 kHz, 10 kHz,) and work up.  Oh is this a 4 point Van-der-Pauw type thing or a four point Kelvin connection?

Comment: Which AC characteristics are you interested in? AC is trickier to measure; however, 1 MHz is not that high so depending on what you want to measure you may be able to use an old analog scope or even cobble something together.

Comment: Just run 1 MHz through it and probe current and voltage at the same time with an oscilloscope. V=IR. You can look for phase shift also. There are current probes with > 1 MHz bandwidth.

Comment: @mkeith That helps get me on the right path.  If you put that as an answer I'll accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering about the geometry/size of your probe. 1Mhz isn't that high, but if the contacts are close together your probe might have a significant capacity. Also the contact between wire and probe is more important at higher frequencies.

You can verify/calibrate your equipment with different pieces of solid copper wire for which the skin effect is known.